# How can I add dependencies to local patched packages?

Tags: python, dependencies, package, setuptools, in-house-distribution

I am creating an in-house Python package for my company, and one package of its dependencies has a critical bug/misfeature (for what I would do, at least). I patched it and submitted the patch, but it isn’t merged to the upstream branch yet (and seems not going to be available on the PyPI soon). I have to use this patched feature right now, but how can I specify a dependency of this local patched package by using setuptools/Distribute?

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most general terms, call your package like eg orig-package-name-1.2.3-COMPANYNAME1.ext (where ext can be egg, tar.gz, tar.bz2, zip, ...) and add your location with find_links mechanism. Some inspiring example could be found in the [Distribute’s documentation](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#creating-your-own-package-index)

Then change your packages to depend on that particular version. All this is simplest to do with buildout, where production configuration is explicitly bound to desired versions (plus maybe md5 sums can be specified).